# Can we connect a source system that have no internet connectivity through Azure data factory self-hosted IR?

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where the source system is in a private network and has no internet connectivity, But I have configured a Self-Hosted IR VM in the same network and has an active Internet connection. So my question is that, is this possible to copy data from this source (No Internet) by using Azure data factory self-hosted IR.

Comment: Did you try anything and get any error message?

Comment: @LeonYue, I didn't try it yet, As of now I just want to know if it is possible or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime), if you want to perform data integration securely in a private network environment, which doesn't have a direct line-of-sight from the public cloud environment, you can install a self-hosted IR on premises environment behind your corporate firewall, or inside a virtual private network. The self-hosted integration runtime only makes outbound HTTP-based connections to open internet.

If your self-hosted IR status shows as running then that means you can make connection from ADF to your private network or on-premises network.
But in this scenario, depending upon the connectivity configuration between your internet enabled VM and source system, you may or may not be able to copy the data. So, try to create a linked service for your source and check is test connection is getting success or not.